# How to get class type statically in swift

Tags: swift

As the question may seem duplicated, I point out first that this is not asking for how to get a class type from an instance ( answer is using `type(of:)` ).

```
protocol Owner {
    static func name() -> String
}

extension Owner {
    static func name() -> String {
        return "\(self)"
    }
}

class Foo {
    var ownerName: String
    init(with owner: Owner.Type) {
        ownerName = owner.name()
    }
}

class Bar: Owner {
    var foo = Foo(with: Bar.self)
}
```

The code above simply works, but imagine that I want to rename the class `Bar` to `BarBar` then I need to change the initialization of `foo` to `Foo(with: BarBar.self)` manually. Is there any keyword that can be used instead of `ClassName.self` (e.g. `Bar.self` `BarBar.self`) to get the class type? Something like `Self` or `Class` (they don't compile actually)

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to get the type of a class statically without explicitly writing the name of it (such as `BarBar.self`). Just as a sidenote - you're also missing a `-> String` in your protocol extension's `name()`.

Comment: If you perform the rename using a Refactor (which you need to do anyway, to ensure all usages are consistently renamed), then this would get changed. It's really quite a non-issue

Comment: Xcode doesn't support swift refactoring for now.

Comment: I believe that what you want is in the proposal [Swift Evolution 0068](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your whole question is a red herring and that `type(of:self)` is *exactly* what you want to say. In that case, the problem is merely that `var foo` is declared as an instance property. There are special rules for when you are allowed to say `self` while initializing an instance property (rightly, because `self` is exactly what does not yet exist during initialization). However, there are ways around that, as I have explained elsewhere; you can make this a *computed* instance property, or a *lazy* instance property, which is initialized by a function to be executed later, and then you *are* allowed to say `type(of:self)`.

Comment: But `foo` need to be an instance property XD

Comment: Making it `lazy` works fine as long as the `foo` is not used in the initializer, which is true most of the time. @matt, would you edit the answer and then I can accept it?

Comment: Hi, @matt, I'm back here. The lazy initialization is a good idea. But there's still some problem. Let's say there is a subclass `class Barbar: Bar` and it has an lazy property `lazy var foofoo = { Foo(with: self) }()`. Then the properties become `foofoo.ownerName == "BarBar"` and `foo.ownerName == "BarBar"`, they are same because of the polymorphism. But what I actually wanted is `foo.ownerName == "Bar"` and `foofoo.ownerName == "BarBar"`